# Correct Way to use Relative Path to Access a file in Client Bin in a Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-5.0, relative-path, bin

I have a WCF Service that I call from the client of my silverlight application, and I pass it a string filename parameter and a string parameter containing xml. In the service method I construct an XDocument instance containing the xml string, and then save it to a file in the ClientBin folder on the server. I have been using an absolute path, and now am trying to switch to a relative path, but am unsure how to do it correctly. My code looks like this:

```
public void WriteXmlToServer(string filename,string xmlString)
{
    //xml document to hold the information for the group that is registered
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(XDocument.Parse(xmlString.ToString())); 

    XDocument DataInFile = new XDocument();

    try
    {
        xDoc.Save(Path.Combine("..\\ClientBin\\", filename));
        //the complete absolute path to the .xml file ->C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SL_xMonitor_Frontend_RefactorV1_Backup82212\SL_xMonitor_Frontend_RefactorV1.sln       
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {     
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am currently getting this exception message:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024893
  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\ClientBin\ServerGroups.xml'.
```

Could someone please instruct me on the correct way to use a relative path to a file in the client bin in a Silverlight application?

Comment: You want to save something on server from client?

Answer (score 0):

Try a single `.` instead of `..` as `..` means to back up one directory level before descending into the Directory you want, where as `.` means starting at the current Directory, then descend into the desired directory.